# C++ : Declaring struct return-type function in header file

Tags: c++, data-structures, header-files

I have a header file "`check.h`" that defines the following `struct`:

```
#ifndef CHECK_H
#define CHECK_H
#include<string>
struct Test{
    std::string check;

};

#endif
```

I have another header file "`test.h`" that has the following function with return type as the `struct Test` defined above:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
#include<string>
#include "check.h"
Test display(std::string);
#endif
```

But even on including `"check.h"` in this header file I get an `unable to resolve identifier` error. What do I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you post the code? Or at least some more of it?

Comment: Did you `#include <string>` and `using std::string` or otherwise bring in a `string` name into those headers?

Comment: Is this C or C++? In C it would require `struct Test` and am not sure if `string` is `std::string` in the posted code or some `typedef`.

Comment: I've posted some more of my code. Hope it helps! It's in C++.

Comment: @hmjd: C doesn't have a `::` operator, or standard headers without `.h`, so it's pretty clearly C++.

Comment: @unwind, the code has changed since it was originally posted and `::` was nowhere to be seen.

Comment: What exactly does the error message say, and which line of code does it refer to? Hopefully, that will tell you which identifier it's unable to resolve.

Comment: Seems like I need to change return type to 'struct Test'! It works now.

Comment: @Enigman, that doesn't make sense. `struct` is unrequired in C++.

Comment: what `unable to resolve identifier` message do you get? can you post it?

Comment: You are claiming that the wrong solution fixes your problem. Could it be that your compiler does not support standard C++ very well? What compiler are you using?

Comment: The current code compiles with gcc(mingw) 4.6.1. Either you are using some other compiler, or the code you are struggling with are not equal to your example.

Comment: I guess that struct Test function() could be interpreted as a forward declaration. Which would explain why it "works". The real problem is still there.

Comment: Really sorry guys. I'm using NetBeans and it showed the `unable to resolve` error which went away only on adding `struct`. Without `struct` it doesn't show any error on compiling though!

Comment: @hmjd: It can be required in C++ if there's something else in scope called `Test`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, thanks. I don't think I have come across that scenario before.

Comment: @Enigman I would suggest that you extend the code to bring in the part which actually makes this code fail to compile, in that way this question might actually be useful to other in a similar situation.

Comment: Hey, the error was 'shown' in netbeans, beside the line where I have declared the function with struct test return type. I later realized that it however compiled successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be fine as long as you haven't defined something else (such as a variable or function) with the name `Test`.

If you have, then you need to make it clear that you're referring to the class and not the other thing:

```
struct Test display(std::string);
^^^^^^
```

although a much better solution would be to avoid using the same name for different things.

Answer (score 0):

You should return `struct Test` because `test.h` defines a struct not a type.

Or just change your struct definition to a typedef:

```
typedef struct s_Test{
    string check;
} Test;
```

See wikipedia [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29)

Comment: But isn't `struct` required to be mentioned only in C?

Comment: The question is tagged C++, and uses a C++ header. This answer would be wrong for C++.

Comment: @Enigman: Sometimes it's needed in C++ to disambiguate if there's something else (e.g. a variable or function) with the same name as the class. Of course, the dodgy `typedef` wouldn't help there either.