# How do I properly declare a function returning own-defined type, both in the header and the .cpp file?

Tags: c++, struct, namespaces, header-files, return-type

I am new to working with headers and the whole abstractization thing in C++ and I have noticed that: when you declare a function in the .cpp file, you first specify the return-type of the function, followed by `namespace_name :: function_signature`, the name and the arguments of the function being the same you have already specified in the .h file. Yet, how should I write the signature of a function whose forward-declaration ( if that is how the signatures in the .h file  are called ) is present in the same namespace as the own-defined return type? ( sorry for the verbose, code is simpler than my question; see below for clarification )

I want to find the longest sequence of equal numbers in a given array. These are my files:

```
//"sequences.h" file
#ifndef LAB1_SEQUENCES_H
#define LAB1_SEQUENCES_H

namespace Sequences{

/**
 * Abstract Data Type for a sequence
 */
struct seq{
    int i;
    int j;
};

/**
 * Finds longest sequence of equal integers
 * arr - array to search in
 * n - number of elements in the array
 */
seq longest_equal(int* arr, int n);

}
#endif //LAB1_SEQUENCES_H
```

.

```
//"sequences.cpp" file
#include "sequences.h"


//Sequences :: seq Sequences :: longest_equal(int *arr, int n)
//seq Sequences :: longest_equal(int *arr, int n)
//struct seq longest_equal(int *arr, int n)
//Sequences :: struct seq longest_equal(int *arr, int n)
{
int i = 0, j = i + 1;
int lmax = -1, iR = -1, jR =-1 ; // lmax ar trebui sa fie 1 sau -1 ?
while (j < n )
{
    if (arr[i] == arr[j]) j ++;
    else
    {
        if (j - i > lmax) { lmax = j - i; iR = i; jR = j; }
        i = j;
        j = i + 1;
    }
}
if (lmax > 1) return Sequences :: seq(iR, jR);
return Sequences::seq(-1, -1);
}
```

Now, I do not know how I can make my `longest_equal` function in the .cpp file return `seq` type (I am regarding both the signature in the header file and the signature in the .cpp file, as well as what I should virtually write before the return commands at the end of the function's implementation, in the .cpp file).

I have tried the commented lines of code just before the first accolade in the second file as signatures of the function. I have also read the answers to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838531/c-declaring-struct-return-type-function-in-header-file) and some answers of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34825868/returning-a-struct-from-function) and tried something myself, yet to no avail.

Comment: You need to regard the namespace in the .cpp file as well

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann what do you mean by that? I have trie all the commented options, but each of them gives an error

Comment: You could simply enclose the implementation in the .cpp file in `namespace Sequences{ ... }`, same as you do in the header; then just write `seq longest_equal(int* arr, int n) { ... }` inside. If for some reason you insist on spelling out full names, then `Sequences::seq Sequences::longest_equal(int *arr, int n) { ... }` is the correct form.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thank you for the comment, but then I would have an unresolved reference in the namespace in the header...`seq` would not be recognizable

Comment: Why would it not be? I'm not sure I understand. Show the exact code you are compiling, and the exact error messages you receive for that code.

Answer (score 0):

Forward declarations are used to reduce header dependencies. Since your `struct seq` doesn't require any headers and all it has is data members, it makes little sense to forward declare it. You should *define* it in the header along with the function *declaration* (and have the function *definition* in the `.cpp`).

You can use a forward declaration only for taking and returning structures and classes by reference or pointer. In your particular case the `struct seq` is a simple aggregate value, a tuple with named fields, conceptually. It is not *abstract data type* as you state because there is nothing abstract about it, it is rather concrete and have no behaviour. An [*abstract data type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) is defined in terms of an behaviour (functions and member functions), rather than data members it is composed of.

Comment: "You can use a forward declaration only for taking and returning structures and classes by reference" - not quite. A forward declaration is also sufficient for function return types.